# Django Model with API as data source

Tags: python, django, django-models, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a new model which uses the https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer api as a data source as i want to have additional info on the user.

Using a computed property on the model does not work as it is going to query for each instance in the set.

So, i want to have the model relate to a new model which has the api as it´s data source.

I could not find anything on this topic, besides maybe abusing the `from_db()`  method, if this even works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you're trying to do is to cache data from an external API that relates to, and augments/enriches, your user model data. If so, you can simply [use a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) (instead of Django's default; this is a highly-recommended practice anyway) and then simply store the external API data in serialized form in a `TextField` attribute of your custom user model (let's call it `user_extras`; you can write model methods that serializes and deserializes this field for convenience upon access in your views).

The key challenge then is how to keep `user_extras` fresh, without doing something terrible performance-wise or hitting some constraint like API call limits. As you said, we can't do API queries in computed properties. (At least not synchronously.) One option then is to have a batch job/background task that regularly goes through your user database to update the `user_extras` in some controlled, predictable fashion.